# how to set domain of 2d fourier transformin in numpy

Tags: numpy

I want to use numpy FFT2 module.

For example, I have the values of function in discrete grid
x=(0,1,2,3,4,5), y=(0,1,2,3,4,5), z=exp(x+y)
So my code will be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,5,6)
y=np.linspace(0,5,6)
xmesh,ymesh=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z=np.exp(xmesh+ymesh)
plt.scatter(xmesh.ravel(),ymesh.ravel(),z.ravel())
plt.show()
```

This shows the image such as
[image]
Now, I want to transform this into k-space, using Fourier transform.
For z value, I just used

```
fft_z=np.fft.fft2(z)
```

But how do I determine its domain?
To plot scatter plot like above(In fact, I'll plot heatmap), I have to
determine where these fft_z values lies on, and make meshgrid in k-space like above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.fft.fftfreq` to generate the frequency domain automatically.
Just as a reminder, the relationship between the frequency and time domains is
df = 1/(N*dt) and 1/dt is the full bandwidth (BW) of the frequency domain.

It is important to notice the fftfreq generates an array from -BW/2 to BW/2, however in an unconventional way. Starting from 0 to BW/2, -BW/2 to -df. This is because of the periodicity of the discrete Fourier transform, so the data will be shown centred around zero. You can use np.fft.fftshift to realing the data before plotting. You can see an example bellow.

```
fft_z = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(z))
fx = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[0],x[1]-x[0]))
fy = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[0],y[1]-y[0]))
```

you can plot the result using:

```
plt.pcolormesh(fx,fy,fft_z.real)
```

OBS: fft_z.real to take the real part of fft_z, which is a complex number. The same can be used to the imaginary part. `plt.pcolormesh(fx,fy,fft_z.imag)`

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not familar to FFT, so I wonder about the range of function. If I write code as
`x=np.linspace(0,1,2)
y=np.linspace(0,1,2)
xmesh,ymesh=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z=np.exp(xmesh+ymesh)`
then we get array z as [z(0,0),z(0,1),z(1,0),z(1,1)]. So If we just draw it using `plt.scatter(xmesh.ravel(),ymesh.ravel(),z.ravel())`, we get right picture. But does that apply to np.fft.fftfreq? I tried that code, and it generates fx,fy in range -BW/2~BW/2. So If I draw it in the same way as above, `fxmesh,fymesh=np.meshgrid(fx,fy)
plt.scatter(fxmesh.ravel(),fymesh.ravel(),fft_z.ravel())` do I get right answer?

Comment: You definitely can use `meshgrid` and `scatter` to plot the fft result, but remember that `fft_z` is a complex number so you might want to choose between `real` and `imag` parts of your fft result. However, I am not sure if the scatter plotting style will be a good choice for visualising this kind of data, as the circles may overlap each other and the graph will be really confusing, a colormap seems to be much more applicable here. Having said that, it still depends on what you want to show. Cheers